# videojs is not defined for videojs.options.flash.swf

Tags: google-chrome, video.js, rtmp

I try to use video.js for RTMP live streaming. Below is my HTML code

I can play the demo.mp4 video without any problem. However, when I try to play the try.mp4, the error is "CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED No compatible source was found for this media video.min.js:12"

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/5606. I already tried this solution, but it doesn't work.
I try to use the "https://unpkg.com/browse/video.js@7.6.0/dist/video.min.js" however, it leads to a new error: "videojs is not defined", located at videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf". video-js.swf file and my HTML file are under the same path. I try to use "https://unpkg.com/videojs-swf@5.4.1/dist/video-js.swf" and it has the same error.

My system: win10

chrome: 76.0.3809.100

Thus, there are two bugs and I don't know which one is the bug that I need to solve and it confuses me. thanks for any kind of help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
    <title>myplayer_first</title>
    <!--<script 
    src="https://unpkg.com/browse/video.js@7.6.0/dist/video.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="video.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/browse/videojs- flash@2.2.0/dist/videojs-flash.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/browse/video.js@7.6.0/dist/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <script>
   <!-- videojs.options.flash.swf = "https://unpkg.com/videojs-swf@5.4.1/dist/video-js.swf";-->
   videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <video id="myvideo" width=960 height=540 class="video-js vjs-default-skin" data-setup='{"techorder" : ["flash","html5"]}'  muted="muted">
   <!-- <source src="rtmp://10.51.197.90/vod/try.mp4"  type="rtmp/mp4">  -->
  <source src="demo.mp4"  >       
  </video>
  <script> 
  var player = videojs('myvideo', {}, function(){console.log('videojs is coming')})
  player.play();
  </script>``
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Possibly a CORS issue. Does the server itself have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` whitelisted?

Comment: Sorry for the late update. I put the html file on the server, then it works. It can play the RTMP stream from the other website server and the video on my server but it cannot play my live RTMP stream built on my server. The vlc can play my rtmp stream and when i play it, there are no errors reported in the console and the screen is not totally black, it is black with white spots (area) and dynamically changed.  I now use flv.js to play the live stream, it works.